# get upcoming games after weekend

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a website to show the upcoming games for the weekend. 
The problem is that with the code I have, when the day passes, the upcoming game disappears. I want to keep the games of Friday, Saturday and Sunday as upcoming games until Sunday passes.

This is what I have now for my sql query:

```
$res1= mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT * 
  FROM kalender               //table containing all dates upcoming games
 WHERE datum >= curdate()     //selecting next games and from which division
   AND afdeling = 'Ere'
 ORDER 
    BY datum                  //order them on date
 LIMIT 0 , 7                  //select only the next 7 upcoming games
");?>
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So basically you are asking us to take a simple query and make you a much more complex query. SO is not where you come to get code written for you

Comment: @RiggsFolly that was not my intention. English is not my native language and maybe I didn't explained myself enough. I've check almost every resource on google and SO to find a solution or clue but found nothing. I thought I've missed something 'simple' and that's why I posted the question. I'm not asking to rewrite my whole code. Just a pointing in right direction will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you could change "curdate()" to something that returns the date of the last friday during the weekend, for example:

```
date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL if(weekday(curdate())>4,weekday(curdate())-4,0) DAY)
```

Remember to add clarifying comments because I doubt this code will be obvious to anyone that is not aware of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: That helped a lot. Especially the "if" clause in the SQL statement. I've changed "curdate()" in my code to:                                                       
'if(weekday(curdate())=6,curdate()-2,if(weekday(curdate())=5,curdate()-1,if(weekday(curdate())<=4,curdate(),curdate())))'